# vb 2010, deleting rows in datagridview to update access table

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, oledb

I have declared these as private in the form.

```
Private callLogConnection As New OleDbConnection()
Private schDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From tbl_schtime", _ callLogConnection)
Private schCommmandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(schDataAdapter)
Private schDataTable As New DataTable
Private schRowPosition As Integer = 0
Private qryexceptionDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From  _ qry_exceptionUpdate", callLogConnection)
Private exceptionBindingSource = New BindingSource()
Private exception2BindingSource As New BindingSource
Private exceptionCommandBuilder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New _ OleDbCommandBuilder(qryexceptionDataAdapter)
Private qryexceptionDataTable As New DataTable
Private qryexceptionRowPostiion As Integer = 0
Private tbl_ExceptionDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
Private exceptionDataTable As New DataTable
```

I have declared these objects in the form load

```
qryexceptionDataAdapter.Fill(qryexceptionDataTable)
'linking the qryexception table to binding source
exceptionBindingSource.DataSource = qryexceptionDataTable
'showing the binding source in the datagrid view
dgvExceptions.DataSource = exceptionBindingSource
```

This is my Save button command to update my table from datagridview.

```
Private Sub btnSaveException_Click(sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveException.Click
    Try
        Me.Validate()
        Me.qryexceptionDataAdapter.Update(Me.tbl_ExceptionDataSet.Tables("qry_exceptionUpdates"))
        Me.tbl_ExceptionDataSet.AcceptChanges()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

    End Sub code here
```

But I keep getting:

```
System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Overload resolution failed because no Public 'Update' is most specific for these arguments:
    'Public Function Update(dataTable As System.Data.DataTable) As Integer':
        Not most specific.
    'Public Overrides Function Update(dataSet As System.Data.DataSet) As Integer':
        Not most specific.
    'Public Function Update(dataRows As System.Data.DataRow()) As Integer':
        Not most specific.
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.OverloadResolution.ResolveOverloadedCall(String MethodName, List`1 Candidates, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, BindingFlags LookupFlags, Boolean ReportErrors, ResolutionFailure& Failure)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.OverloadResolution.ResolveOverloadedCall(String MethodName, MemberInfo[] Members, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, BindingFlags LookupFlags, Boolean ReportErrors, ResolutionFailure& Failure)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.ResolveCall(Container BaseReference, String MethodName, MemberInfo[] Members, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, BindingFlags LookupFlags, Boolean ReportErrors, ResolutionFailure& Failure)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.CallMethod(Container BaseReference, String MethodName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, BindingFlags InvocationFlags, Boolean ReportErrors, ResolutionFailure& Failure)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.ObjectLateCall(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateCall(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn)
   at Call_Log.CallLogForm.btnSaveException_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\mdutton\Desktop\Call Log\Call Log\CallLogForm.vb:line 174
```

Comment: When does that error come up? during page load or when you click your submit button

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in your call stack:

`Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateCall`.

This means that VB is trying to figure out which overload it should be calling at run time instead of design time. And the exception that is being thrown most likely means that:

```
Me.tbl_ExceptionDataSet.Tables("qry_exceptionUpdates")
```

evaluates to Nothing because there are 3 overloads that take single object parameters (which the exception has helpfully listed for you) that could potentially match your request.

So, there are two things to fix here:

1) Set Option Strict On in the project properties. From the [Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> In addition to disallowing implicit narrowing conversions, Option
>   Strict generates an error for late binding. An object is late bound
>   when it is assigned to a variable that is declared to be of type
>   Object.
>
> Because Option Strict On provides strong typing, prevents unintended
>   type conversions with data loss, disallows late binding, and improves
>   performance, its use is strongly recommended.

2) Once you do the above, you will still end up with a run time error, but now it will be that the DataTable parameter cannot be null (Nothing), so you need to fix this as well.

You may have a typo in your sample code, but the table name in the button click event does not match what you have in your select statement (`qry_exceptionUpdates` vs `_qry_exceptionUpdate`).

If possible, you should specify the table name one time in a global or module-level constant so that you do not run into this type of naming issue.